# Adding a table in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to do something pretty simple - add a table to my database through phpMyAdmin. For some reason the following throws up 5 errors:

```
CREATE TABLE group (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB
```

phpMyAdmin tells me that the following is wrong about it.

> The name of the entity was expected. (near "group" at position 13)
>   An opening bracket was expected. (near "group" at position 13)
>   At least one column definition was expected. (near " " at position 12)
>   Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "id" at position 26)
>   Unrecognized statement type. (near "INT" at position 29)

I'm wondering why this error comes about, and whether I can do anything to fix it.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single tick marks around the word "group" like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `group` (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The problem is "group" is a reserved word. You can learn more about that here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: the question is: *"why?" - there is a specific reason. (as per original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43263151/1)

Comment: @ Fred -ii- I added your link, but to be pedantic, that wasn't the question ;) Although of course it's useful to explain the answer :)

Comment: *"that wasn't the question"* - It should be, IMHO. Say I hadn't closed the question with the duplicate for the often-asked problem where 95% of the time they don't Google their error (which was the case here, I'm sure), the OP or anyone else visiting the question/answer and not knowing the reason why, how else will they know? Think about it and put yourself in their shoes ;-) we were all once 'there" at one time.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

"group" is a reserved keyword in MySQL, you'll need to wrap it in the back tick character like so to escape that:

```
    CREATE TABLE `group` (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked just fine with back ticks.